# CakePHP3 - How to get hasMany-Association for child elements

Tags: cakephp

I have a customer controller with Tree Behavior to store the family:

This works as expected.

e.g.:

```
id  | parent_id | type    | name
----|-----------|---------|--------------
1   | NULL      | husband | Jon Doe 
2   | 1         | wife    | Jane Doe 
3   | 1         | child   | Jim Doe
```

I have also a contracts controller, which is associated correctly with customers.

ContractsTable:

```
$this->belongsTo('Customers', [
    'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

CustomerTable:

```
$this->belongsTo('ParentCustomers', [
    'className' => 'Customers',
    'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
]);
$this->hasMany('ChildCustomers', [
    'className' => 'Customers',
    'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
]);

$this->hasMany('Contracts');
```

Customer view()

```
    $customer = $this->Customers->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['ParentCustomers', 'ChildCustomers', 'Contracts']
    ]);
    debug($customer);
```

This works as expected for the parent customer (husband). I get an object like this one:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Customer) {
    'id' => (int) 1,
    'parent_id' => null,
    'typ' => 'husband',
    'name' => 'Jon Doe',
    'contracts' => [
     (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Contract) {
        'id' => (int) 1,
        'customer_id' => (int) 1,
        'contract_number' => '123456',
        'tariff' => 'SuperTariff ABC'
    }
    'child_customers' => [
     (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Customer) {
        'id' => (int) 2,
        'parent_id' => (int) 1,
        'typ' => 'wife',
        'name' => 'Jane Doe'
     },
      (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\Customer) {
        'id' => (int) 3,
        'parent_id' => (int) 1,
        'type' => 'child',
        'name' => 'Jim Doe'
    }
}
```

But the child customers (wife and/or child) have also contracts, but these are not shown. Is there a 'cakephp'-way to do this or shoud I collect the data for each customer?

Thanks in advance.